# Calculating $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x^2+9)^2} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I try to calculate
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{(x^2+9)^2} dx
$$
I use a book that tells me to replace $\ln x \ $ by $ \ \ln(|x|) + i\phi_z$ where $\phi_z$ denotes the argument of $z$, chosen between $-\frac \pi 2 \ $ and $ \ \frac {3\pi}2$. I don't know why this could work, I hope that you can tell me.

An example shows me to integrate on the set below:
$$
[-R,-\epsilon] 
\ \cup \ 
\{\epsilon e^{i ( \pi - \phi)} :  0 \leq \phi \leq \pi\}
\ \cup \
[\epsilon, R]
\ \cup \
\{Re^{i\phi} : 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi \}
$$
On the set $[\epsilon,R]$ I will get something that will get near to the wanted integral.
On the set $[-R, -\epsilon]$ I got
$$
\int_\epsilon ^R \frac{\ln x}{(x^2+9)^2} dx 
\ + \
\pi i  \cdot \int_\epsilon^R \frac{1}{(x^2+9)^2} dx
$$
I think I can show that the integral on the two half circles will be small for big $R$ and small $\epsilon$. I need your help for finding the residues in $\pm 3 i$.
I thought that Í would need the rule:
$$
Res_{z=a} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} \quad = \quad \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}
$$
But I can't take the derivative of $|z|$. Could you give me a hint to go on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are actually telling you to relate the given integral to a specified contour integral of $f(z)=\ln z/(z^2+9)^2$, where $f$ is the (unique) analytic continuation of the real function $f(x)=\ln x/(x^2+9)^2$ on $(0,\infty)$ to the specified region.  The $\ln(|x|)+ i\phi_z$ business is how the analytic continuation is defined, but the function to use in the Residue Theorem is just $\ln z/(z^2+9)^2$.  The only residue inside the contour is at $z=3i$.

Comment: Can you tell me why 0 is not a singularity?

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin, you don't have to work about the singularity at $0$ because it's not inside the contour.  That's the point of that second set, the semicircle of radius $\epsilon$.

Comment: But in that case the lower circle should be flipped, isn't it? As I wrote it, the point $0$ lies inside the path.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin, oh gosh, you're right.  Well, they told you wrong.  (Oh, wait, it looks like you've edited the problem. Do you still have a question?)

Comment: I changed it. I hope that it's all right now.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin, yes, I think it is.  Basically, to get a single-valued analytic continuation, they made a slit up the negative imaginary axis (that's the restriction of $\phi_z$ to lie between $-\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$).  Once you make a slit, your contour should not *cross* that slit.  That's why the little semicircle needed to go *above* its center at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = 3\tan\theta$. Then $\frac{1}{(x^2+9)^2} = \frac{\cos^4\theta}{81}$. Your integral then becomes $$ \frac{1}{27}\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^2\theta\ln(3\tan\theta)d\theta$$ Use partial integration, i.e. $u = \ln(3\tan\theta)$ and $dv = \cos^2\theta d\theta$. The rest should follow from integration of elementary trigonometric functions (or at least so I hope).